# Making a webService file smaller

Tags: objective-c, json, http

I'm developing an iOS app, and I have a file, WebService.m, that is now 2300 lines long.  My file contains all the web service calls on my app, with their parsing if successful, like:

```
- (void)searchSettingsWithSuccess:(void (^)(UserSettings *settings))success
                          failure:(void (^)(WKWebServiceError *error))failure
{
    if ([WKUtil isUsingLocalData])
    {
        success([self parseSettingsJsonResponse:[WKUtil loadJsonFile:@"UserSettings"]]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Query the location building from web service
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [self addHeaderAuthToken:manager];
        [self updateSecurityPolicy:manager];
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", API_URL_ROOT, API_URL_USER_SETTINGS];
        [manager GET:url
          parameters:nil
        timeInterval:10
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
             if ([self isSuccessJsonResponse:responseObject])
             {
                 success([self parseSettingsJsonResponse:responseObject]);
             }
             else
             {
                 failure([self parseErrorJsonResponse:responseObject apiUrl:API_URL_USER_SETTINGS]);
             }
         }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             failure([WKWebServiceError errorWithSystemError:error apiUrl:API_URL_USER_SETTINGS]);
         }];
    }
}
```

I then parse it:

```
- (UserSettings*)parseSettingsJsonResponse:(NSDictionary*)responseObject
{
    NSDictionary *data = [WKUtil parseJsonDictionary:[responseObject objectForKey:API_KEY_DATA]];
    if (data == nil)
        return nil;

    UserSettings *settings = [[UserSettings alloc] init];
    settings.doNotDisturbDate = [WKUtil parseJsonDateString:[data objectForKey:API_KEY_DO_NOT_DISTURB_END_TIME] format:DATE_FORMAT_YEAR_TIME];
    settings.isDoNotDisturb = [[WKUtil parseJsonNumberBool:[data objectForKey:API_KEY_IS_DO_NOT_DISTURB]] boolValue];
    settings.isPushNotifications = [[WKUtil parseJsonNumberBool:[data objectForKey:API_KEY_IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS]] boolValue];
    settings.isCrisisAvailable = [[WKUtil parseJsonNumberBool:[data objectForKey:API_KEY_IS_CRISIS_AVAILABLE]] boolValue];
    settings.primaryMobile = [WKUtil parseJsonString:[data objectForKey:API_KEY_PRIMARY_MOBILE]];
    settings.capabilities = [WKUtil parseJsonArray:[data objectForKey:API_KEY_CAPABILITIES]];

    return settings;
}
```

Should I place the parsing of the return data on another file?, or what other method would make this file smaller?

Comment: This question is asking how to make a 2300-line file smaller, yet we're only given 2 methods (are they both part of the file).  We can't guess at what parts of the 2300 lines should be moved into a different class or file.  With that said, the code that's posted here is reviewable... it just doesn't match the plain English question you're asking.  We need to see either the whole file, or the plain English question should be modified to match the posted code.

Comment: Just a head's up. There is a 30,000 byte technical limitation. 2300 lines would most likely exceed that. (Just in case you were thinking of trying to post all of it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try to keep your web-service methods separately in relavent classes.In most cases,we are fetching data-models or some results from webservice so it is better to keep them in relevant files.
For example you can put

```
- (void)searchSettingsWithSuccess:(void (^)(UserSettings *settings))success 
                          failure:(void (^)(WKWebServiceError *error))failure
```

method in controller related to settings.